# Arabic and urdu fonts not displaying properly on my vivo x710L china ROM

Tags: android

I am using vivo xshot model. Arabic and Urdu fonts are not displaying properly. Letters are not connected each other to form a word. I will be really happy to know the way to fix this problem.

Comment: you mean it is not displaying in your application or you talking  generally ?

Comment: @Arif Nouman Khan bro i mean generally. The fonts aren't displaying properly on facebook, instagram, contacts and in message. I can see arabic letters but they are not joined each other to form a complete word.